# TBrowser won't open (ROOT)

Tags: ubuntu, x11, root, xming

I have installed the ROOT program on ubuntu shell, but I have some problems when I try to run the TBrowser. Somehow the TBrowser don’t show up when I type “new TBrowser()” , but instead I get the following message:

```
root [0] new TBrowser() Error in TGClient::TGClient: can’t open display 
“localhost:0.0”, switching to batch mode… In case you run from a remote
ssh session, reconnect with ssh -Y (TBrowser *) 0x55b6b4e54b70
```

I have installed the Xming program and entered `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` in the `~/.bashrc` file, but the problem persists. When I type xclock I get the message: `Error: Can’t open display: localhost:0.0`

So I guess my problem is not with root but with the X server ?

Comment: The problem is that you don't have authority to open a program on the display localhost:0.0. There are lots of potential reasons for this, including there being no display localhost:0.0. Remove the line you added to your .bashrc, it is almost certainly wrong. Xming is a windows program. How are you connecting to your ubuntu machine? Is your ubuntu machine a different machine or is it a WSL install?

Comment: Ok, I removed the "export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0". I don't get any error message's when I type "new TBrowser()", but still the TBrowser won't show up. My ubuntu is a WSL installation (ubuntu shell).

Comment: OK, next question. You start Xming somehow (click on an icon). Are you setting a display number? Are you using it in the default one window mode or the multi-window recommended mode? Does it start a terminal automatically? Is there some kind of "info" icon or srartup dialog box which tells you what display number it is? We need to find the display number as the next step. After that we need to find the authentication (if any).

Comment: I haven't set any display number when I have started Xming. I'm using Multiple windows on  Select display settings, then I use the default settings.

Comment: I have the display number 0